# Create new Place Facebook SDK C#

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, new-operator

I have created an application for wp7, from which you can post your location on facebook via checkin, I just don't know how can I create a new location if it doesn't exist yet?
I don't even know how can I creatit at the facebook site as well.

This is how I post, so that you see what I'm talking about:

```
JsonObject coordinates = new JsonObject();
coordinates.Add("latitude", _latitude);
coordinates.Add("longitude", _longitude);

var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
arguments["access_token"] = _accessToken;
arguments["place"] = selected.ID;
arguments["coordinates"] = coordinates.ToString();

fb.PostAsync("me/checkins", arguments);
```

I hope someone can help. Best Regards

Comment: Facebook places is being dropped http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-20098129-93/facebook-kills-deals-after-just-four-months/

Comment: @Claus Is that really the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dictionary<string, object> position = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
        position.Add("latitude", 25.04098367f);
        position.Add("longitude", 121.54597771f);

        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("access_token", _accessToken);
        parameters.Add("message", "自行開發應用程式打卡");
        parameters.Add("place", "236679649740148");
        parameters.Add("coordinates", position);
```

Comment: parameters.Add("place", "236679649740148"); -> what is this number? 236679649740148

Answer (score 0):

> parameters.Add("place", "236679649740148"); -> what is this number? 236679649740148

this number should be your app ID